# How to display values to one decimal place

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I use the quasar framework and have a q-slider that displays values. I want the decimal places to be limited to 1. I have tried using

**in vue.js**

```
:formatter="value => value.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})"

:formatter="(value) => value.toFixed(1)"
 
<q-item-label class="u-text-user-selected-value">
   {{ eco }}{{ unitSymbol }}
 </q-item-label>


<q-item class="q-item__select q-item__slider">
            <q-slider
              :key="timestampUpdateEco"
              v-model="modelEco"
              @change="(value) => setValueEco(value)"
              :min="minBoundary"
              :max="maxBoundary"
              :step="1"
              label
              color="red-9"
            />
          </q-item>
```

and even tried changing the value where its been assigned.

**in .ts**

```
  private get eco(): number {
    return Number(this.uxOneThermalModuleStore.heatingEco.toFixed(1));
  }

  private async setValueComfort(value: number) {
      if (value < this.minBoundary + diff) {
        value = this.minBoundary + diff;
        this.modelComfort = value;
      }
      await this.uxOneThermalModuleStore.setHeatingComfort(value);
    }
  }
```

but still I get the values like 62.9999999

Comment: it would be helpful if you show us your component/setup function. i don't understand your example fully. where comes `modelEco` from? what is `uxOneThermalModuleStore.heatingEco`?

Comment: Apologies. Now I have added few more lines of code for better clarity of the question-

Comment: it still doesn't seem complete to me. where does  `modelEco` come from? what is `setValueEco(value)` doing?

Answer (score 0):

On my test with [codepen](https://codepen.io/tinohager/pen/OJobEeE) it depends on what is selected as the step so that you can, for example, to 0.1

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-ma-lg">
    <q-slider
      v-model="modelEco"
      :min="0"
      :max="10"
      :step="0.1"
      label
      color="red-9"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    const modelEco = ref(5.2)
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```